# how to allow user keyin data start with 0 when using function (e) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have face some problem that when I using function(e), this will force me to keyin a number not start with 0.

Bellow is my code when force the user to key in month and year,this is actually a bank expired date(not real case,just learning)

```
document.getElementById('cardExpiry').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,2})(\d{0,2})/);
  e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : + x[1] + '/' + x[2] ;
  });
```

[image: This month can't start with 0]

Comment: Don't update the value of an input while the user is editing it, unless you do the fairly-involved work required to prevent your messing up their insertion point position. You'll just irritate the user.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ya, I knew that. So I'm trying to ask is it any possible way to did what I want. If don't then I will just delete this update function....